# Jump to focused/active text field?

Tags: flutter

I have multiple `TextField`s in a `Row` near the bottom of my view. I would like for flutter to automatically scroll to the focused text field when the on screen keyboard comes up.

I couldn't find a way to achieve this in the documentation, but I got it working using this delay function:

```
Future updateScrollPosition(BuildContext context) async {
  await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  RenderBox y = this.context.findRenderObject();
  Offset location = y.localToGlobal(new Offset(0.0, 0.0));
  CustomSingleChildScrollView.of(context).controller.jumpTo(location.dy);
}
```

This seems far more complicated than necessary and any better solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Scrollable.ensureVisible(context)` ?

Comment: Thanks @Darky. I tried that but didn't notice it was an async method. I gave it another try and it worked a treat. thanks !